# Переход на полную версию из мобильной версии сайта

Tags: дефект, дизайн, мобильная-версия

Присутствует проблема с обработкой курсора мыши на ссылке "полная версия" в подвале страницы мобильной версии сайта:

[image: нет руки]

Как видим, отображается курсор выделения текста, хотя должен быть курсор с "рукой", как это сделано для всех остальных ссылок в указанной области:

[image: есть рука]

Проверено в FF 48.0.2.

Как оказалось, [ситуация эта известная](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-to-pointer-when-hovering-full-site-on-mobile) и сделано это намеренно.

Comment: Эммм.... А разве на мобильных устройствах есть мышь?

Comment: @Naumov речь о мобильной версии сайта, а не о мобильной устройстве. Более того, даже на мобильном устройстве можно иметь курсор и подключенную мышь.

Comment: Полная версия - это JS вызов, а не ссылка. Странный метод смены, ну не мне судить, а поправить надо.

Comment: @Other для пользователя это именно ссылка, а детали реализации важны разработчику :)